# RoR - How To Count & Display Comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm looking to have a count of the number of comments left under an article and display it on the index page beside that particular article - like the example here in red circles. Any suggestions as to how I might do this?

The picture is an example of what I'm trying to do, its not my site.

[image]

Comment: Enough snarkyness. How about you post some good old code, ya? Rails code. Code that tells us what your models are, what you have in your controller. Most probably the answer is article.comments.size :)

Comment: This isn't my website, it's just an example to explain what I'm trying to do - "a picture paints 1,000....." and all that!

Comment: If that picture paints a thousand, then some code would paint a million.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a good candidate for `Rails.cache`. Every time you create a new comment simply increment that cache counter using the post id.

If the cache entry does not exist, do a simple `article.comments.count` (depends on your domain model of course) query and re-cache it.

Comment: And then your counts are lost the first time the server restarts or your cache is cleared.

Comment: That's up to you. You can persist across server restarts, RTFM.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html

Comment: ? A cache is place to store data that is expensive to compute or otherwise generate. Its not meant to be your primary datastore. Also, you have updated your answer since I posted my comment.

Comment: Yes, continuous improvement is the purpose of this site :) And you're right, this data (the number of comments) is already available (you just need calculate it). There is no need to do that every time when you can cache it.

Answer (score 0):

Storing it in a cache is one idea, yes.

But storing it in a `counter_cache` column is probably a better idea. That way even if your server was restarted somehow you wouldn't loose the cached values. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html, section 4.1.2.4.

Comment: tell me more?? Where would I start with your idea? Is it a stable way to do this?